# Azure DevOps resources repo: self

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Can someone please explain or provide documentation for

```
resources:
  - repo: self
```

in the azure-pipelines.yml files?  I cannot find any documentation for it.

Here's the official Azure docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"self" means "the repository that the YAML file is in".

Comment: How do you know that?

Answer (score 4):

[Daniel Mann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/781754/daniel-mann) answered this question.  It turns out, I did not need the `repo: self` part.  This part is what I actually put in my YAML `azure-pipelines.yml` file and it is working for us.  Thanks again!

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
      - features/*
      - bugs/*
    paths:
      exclude:
        - README.md

jobs:
   - template: path/to/backendRepo/azure-pipelines.yml
     parameters:
       componentName: BackEndStuff
   - template: path/to/frontendRepo/azure-pipelines.yml
     parameters:
       componentName: FrontEndStuff
```

Answer (score 3):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#access-to-github-repositories
I was wondering the same, and managed to find this, that actually documents what the earlier answers describe